# ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have the following interface:

[image: DataGrid]

When an item is added into the `DataGrid`, the `Total column` will update according to (price * quantity), and the total `TextBox` will also have the total of all the rows added.

However, when I change the quantity of a row, the `Total column` updates, but the total `TextBox` does not.

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
 public partial class pgCheckout : Page {

    ObservableCollection<SaleItem> items = new ObservableCollection<SaleItem>();

    public pgCheckout() {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgItems.ItemsSource = items;
        dgItems.Loaded += SetMinWidths;
        items.CollectionChanged += setTotal;
    }

    public void setTotal(object source, EventArgs e) {
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach(SaleItem i in items) {
            total += i.Total;
        }

        txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();
    }


    public void SetMinWidths(object source, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (var column in dgItems.Columns) {
            if (column.DisplayIndex != 0) {
                column.MinWidth = column.ActualWidth;
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        items.RemoveAt(dgItems.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        bool exist = false;
        foreach (SaleItem i in items) {
            if (i.ItemID.Equals(txtItemID.Text))
                exist = true;
        }

        if (exist) {
            lblErr.Content = "Item already exist";
            txtItemID.Text = "";
        }

        else {

            using (var db = new PoSEntities()) {
                var query = from i in db.Items
                            where i.ItemID.Equals(txtItemID.Text.Trim())
                            select i;
                var itm = query.FirstOrDefault();
                if (itm == null) {
                    lblErr.Content = "Invalid Item";
                    txtItemID.Text = "";
                }
                else {
                    txtItemID.Text = "";
                    lblErr.Content = "";
                    items.Add(new SaleItem() {
                        Num = items.Count + 1,
                        ItemID = itm.ItemID,
                        Name = itm.Name,
                        Price = decimal.Round(itm.Price, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
                        Quantity = 1,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void txtItemID_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter) {
            btnAdd_Click(txtItemID, e);
        }
    }
}

class SaleItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private decimal price;
    public decimal Price {
        get { return price; }
        set {
            this.price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }
    public int quantity;
    public int Quantity {
        get { return quantity; }
        set {
            this.quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }

    public decimal Total {
        get { return decimal.Round(Price * Quantity, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the `SaleItem` class?

Comment: The SaleItem class is included, near the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` fire when something is added or deleted from the collection not the individual members being update.

```
...
else 
{
    txtItemID.Text = "";
    lblErr.Content = "";
    SaleItem newItem = new SaleItem() {
                    Num = items.Count + 1,
                    ItemID = itm.ItemID,
                    Name = itm.Name,
                    Price = decimal.Round(itm.Price, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
                    Quantity = 1 };
     newItem.PropertyChanged += 
             new PropertyChangedEventHandler(newSaleItem_PropertyChanged);

    items.Add(newItem);
 }
 ...
```

And this is the `newSaleItem_PropertyChanged`:

```
void newSaleItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    setTotal(null, null);
}
```

Comment: I see. How should I get around this?

Comment: If your `SaleItem` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` then you can use `PropertyChanged` event for every `SaleItem`. I'm going to edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ObservableCollection<SaleItem> items = new ObservableCollection<SaleItem>();
```

must be a propery

change it to

```
public ObservableCollection<SaleItem> items {get;set;}
```

and do the new in the constructor

or make the get function create new object if one doesn't exist

you must have public getter/setter to use binding

Answer (score 0):

Your `SaleItem` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then you will have `PropertyChanged` event and you can subscribe to it. Using INotifyPropertyChanged will be good for binding.