# Why doesn't my ObservationCollection have any PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#

[image]

Why doesn't my ObservationCollection have any PropertyChanged event?
I checked the documentation and it should contain a PropertyChanged event that's triggered every time the property of the class gets changed. Is it not the case?

```
public class ControlObjectsPropertyOnHold  //TODO change to ObservableCollection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Rhino.DocObjects.ObjRef ObjRef { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ObjGuid { get; set; }

    public ControlObjectsPropertyOnHold(string name, Rhino.DocObjects.ObjRef objRef, System.Guid objGuid)
    {
        if (null != name)
        {
            Name = name;
            ObjRef = objRef;   //Place-holders in case there are more to store
            ObjGuid = objGuid;
        }
    }
        }
```

**Edit: Took EventHorizon's advice but still doesn't work.**
**When ControlObjectsPropertyOnHold.Name is changed, nothing fires.**

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has the `PropertyChanged` event. It actually has two.

The first is the public *PropertyChanged* event as specified by the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. But *ObservableCollection* implements it as an [explicit interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation) (note how the [respective _ObservableCollection<T>_documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.system-componentmodel-inotifypropertychanged-propertychanged) shows that the event is implemented as *System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged* -- the interface name as part of the event name indicates an explicit interface implementation; the Remarks section of this documentation also mentions this fact). This event only becomes accessible when you cast the *ObservableCollection* instance as `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
var myObsColl = new ObservableCollection<string>();
((INotifyPropertyChanged) myObsColl).PropertyChanged += (sender, ea) => {};
```

The second is a protected *PropertyChange* event. But this is not an implementation of the event from the *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface, because of its `protected` access modifier. Internally, *ObservableCollection<T>* forwards (un)subscriptions to the public *INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged* event to this protected event (see the related implementation in the [dotnet/runtime github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c1c33b2ab2e280846c18bc1f024ccc375ad1519a/src/libraries/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ObservableCollection.cs#L71-L78)).

(Side note: Typically, you would not need to care about ObservableCollection<T>'s *PropertyChanged* event. It should be sufficient to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event -- whenever this event is raised you know the content of the ObservableCollection<T> instance has changed.)

Comment: Most likely the best answer from a new contributor I have ever seen. Well done, congrats.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the fast reply! Unfortunately it didn't work. When the property of the <T> is changed, the collection didn't fire the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: @Wiley - That’s not what the propertychanged of the observablecollection does. It only fires the event when a property of the collection itself change, and NOT for items within the collection. You would need to register on each items propertychanged individually.

Comment: @Wiley - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698195/observablecollection-collectionchanged-not-firing or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068379/observablecollection-onpropertychanged-not-firing

Comment: Got it! eventually I created a setter event to detect all property changes! thanks!